# Multiple Aggregate queries as one row

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to do multiple queries that each return a COUNT(*) and have them all in one row.

Currently I have only been able to do this using a union which returns multiple rows.

Here is an example of what I am doing:

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS QuotesCreatedCount, 0 AS QuotesReferredCount

    FROM table1

    WHERE column1 = value 1    

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 0, COUNT(*) 

    FROM table2

    WHERE column1 = value1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use subqueries:

```
select (select count(*)
          from table1
         where column1 = value1) QuotesCreatedCount,
       (select count(*)
          from table2
         where column1 = value1) QuotesReferredCount
```